# linux bash string replace

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash

The actual requirement here is to replace some tags in an nginx server block with values at runtime, fairly standard stuff:

```
server {
    listen 80;# default_server;

    root <sitepath />/<sitename />/sitefiles/public;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name <sitename />;#<- server_domain_or_$

    error_log <sitepath />/<sitename />/platform_dir/logs/nginxerror.log;
    access_log <sitepath />/<sitename />/platform_dir/logs/nginxaccess.log;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have loaded the file into $block and wish to substitute the tag `<sitepath />` with the value of the variable $wwwrooot. While testing with

```
echo "$block" | sed -r "s/<sitepath \/>+/$wwwroot/g"
```

I get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: thanks for edit - looked fine on preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and assume `$wwwrooot` contains slashes.
That's gonna be a problem for your `sed` command, as you've chosen slashes as regex separators. Using a different character (one that's unlikely to be part of your `$wwwrooot`, e.g. `#`) should fix that:

```
echo "$block" | sed -r "s#<sitepath />#$wwwroot#g"
```

Comment: Really ? It detects seperators automatically. Did not see that documented anywhere. Many thanks.

Comment: @DataMechanics The manpage doesn't list it, but at least on Ubuntu, `info sed` gives you a more complete manual. Navigating to `sed Programs > The "s" Command` shows: `The syntax of the 's' (as in substitute) command is 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.  The '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given 's' command. The '/' character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the REGEXP or REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a '\' character.`

Comment: this is not however going back into a variable with block="$block" | sed -r "s#<sitepath />+#$wwwroot#g";

Comment: @DataMechanics what is the problem with this answer? i don't get it... You marked the answer as a solution and you roll back your decision. Why?

Comment: It doesn't detect separators; what you are really doing is dynamically building a `sed` command in shell, not passing a variable's value directly to shell. That means `sed` sees no difference between you passing `"s/<sitepath \/>+/$wwwroot/g"` or `"s/<sitepath \/>+//foo/bar/g" as the first argument.

Comment: @George Vasiliou yes sorry this is so nearly the answer but I need to assign the substitution to a variable as well. Sorry if I was not clear about that

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou can you edit this so I can upvote it as the answer again - really sorry my mistake

Comment: You mean that you need something like this  `block=$(sed -r "s#<sitepath />+#$wwwroot#g" <<<"$block")` ? (works in my bash).